# How to differentiate if *Would* used for Past repetitive action or future hypothesis in English Sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

“Her family wouldn’t appreciate her being known for playing a sport"

What would be the meaning of above sentence without knowing context?.

a) Past representative, Her family never appreciated her of being a sportswomen.

b) Future hypothesis, Her family may not appreciate her of being a sportswomen when the will come to know.

Refer below link for sentence

https://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/meet-thamim-35-year-old-burqa-clad-football-coach-who-is-training-girls-in-chennai-for-the-nationals-354783.html

Answer (score 1):

I think most discerning native speakers, when speaking of a propensity in the past would use the present perfect:

> Her family would not **have appreciated** her being known for playing a sport (so it's a good thing she decided to become an astronaut).

and this would be understood to refer to a  possibility that might yet happen:

> Her family would not **appreciate** her being known for playing a sport (so she would be risking their displeasure if she were to accept that volleyball scholarship).

Comment: I have shared link for my statement. I think sentence mean repetitive past in news.

Comment: Your source is not using the word not to refer to the past  but to a possibility that could become realized in the present. If she were to become known as an athlete, they would not like it. That is why she does not reveal her family name, but only her first name.

Answer (score 0):

B

Based on what the speaker knows about her family, the speaker is hypothesizing that the family will not like her being known as an athlete.

Comment: Plz go through my added link

Comment: It's a hypothesis. Based on the family's strict adherence to their religion, they probably will not be happy about her being known as an athlete.